# Why is the Javascript operator "&&" so weird?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, operator-precedence

```
a = 1;
b = "1";
if (a == b && a = 1) {
    console.log("a==b");
}
```

**The Javascript code above will result in an error** in the `if` statement in Google Chrome 26.0.1410.43:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

I think this is because the variable `a` in the second part of the statement `&&`, `a=1` cannot be assigned. However, when I try the code below, I'm totally confused!

```
a = 1;
b = "1";
if (a = 1 && a == b) {
    console.log("a==b");
}
```

Why is the one statement right but the other statement wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here anyway? What should the code actually do?

Comment: Always use `(` and `)` for operator precedence

Comment: You made a mistake here, you have to write like this `if(a==1 && a == b)`.

Answer (score 60):

[`=` has lower operator precendence than both `&&` and `==`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), which means that your first assignment turns into

```
if ((a == b && a) = 1) {
```

Since you can't assign to an expression in this way, this will give you an error.

Answer (score 21):

The second version is parsed as `a = (1 && a == b)`; that is, the result of the expression `1 && a == b` is assigned to `a`.

The first version does not work because the lefthand side of the assignment is not parsed as you expected. It parses the expression as if you're trying to assign a value to *everything* on the righthand side--`(a == b && a) = 1`.

This is all based on the precedence of the various operators. The problem here stems from the fact that `=` has a lower precedence than the other operators.

Comment: both expressions are parsed perfectly correctly.  They're just not parsed the way the OP expected...

Comment: @Alnitak: Yeah, I think your phrasing is better.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence for the list of operator precedence

Answer (score 6):

Because the order of operations is not what you expect. `a == b && a = 1` is equivalent to `(a == b && a) = 1` which is equivalent to `false = 1`.

If you really want to do the assignment, you need to use parentheses around it: `a == b && (a = 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

In `if (a = 1 && a == b)`,

The operations to be first performed is `1 && a == b`. 1 `&&` the result of `a == b`  is performed. The result of this `&&` operation is assigned to `a`.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. == has a higher precedence than &&. This results in the following evaluation order:
 1. 1
 2. && -> left hand side is already true, don't evaluate right hand side
 3. a = 1

The result is the same as you said. But 1 && a is not evaluated first, it is 1 && (a == b) where the a == b is never evaluated.

In general for a = b && c == d the evaluation order would be (assuming b is falsy):
1. b
2. c == d
3. b && (c == d)
4. a = (b && (c == d))

Comment: My comment is wrong as well ;) You got it right this time. With a && b given b will only be evaluated, if a is true. In my last comment I said a had to be false.